# setting correct indentation using tocloft and conflict between different lists

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation, tocloft

I am writing an article where I both need a list of figures and a list of Lemmas. I can create a custom list using tocloft and this works fine. However, the two lists are indented differently and I cannot figure out how tocloft commands can be used to fix this.

Thanks in advance to everyone providing some hints. Alternative solutions to tocloft for custom lists are appreciated as well.
This is an example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}


\newcommand{\lemma}[1]{
\refstepcounter{lemma}#1\addcontentsline{lem}{lemma}
{\protect\numberline{\thelemma}#1}
}
\newlistof{lemma}{lem}{List of Lemmas}

\begin{document}
Here I write \lemma{Lemma One} and \lemma{Lemma Two} and here I put a figure:
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
$\pi$
\caption{Figure 1}
\end{figure}

\listoffigures
\listoflemma

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine `\cftlemmaindent` and `\cftlemmanumwidth` to `\cftfigindent` and `\cftfignumwidth` respectively

```latex
\renewcommand\cftlemmaindent{\cftfigindent}
\renewcommand\cftlemmanumwidth{\cftfignumwidth}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\newcommand{\lemma}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{lemma}#1\addcontentsline{lem}{lemma}
    {\protect\numberline{\thelemma}#1}%
}
\newlistof{lemma}{lem}{List of Lemmas}
\renewcommand\cftlemmaindent{\cftfigindent}
\renewcommand\cftlemmanumwidth{\cftfignumwidth}

\begin{document}
Here I write \lemma{Lemma One} and \lemma{Lemma Two} and here I put a figure:
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
$\pi$
\caption{Figure 1}
\end{figure}
\listoffigures
\listoflemma
\end{document}
```

[image]